# \rand inside \forloop creates identical values

Tags: programming, random-numbers

I try to create a table with random entries...  By browsing the [random](/questions/tagged/random) tag, I found some help on random number generators and I tried using `lcg`.

Surprisingly I seem to create the same random number over and over again, whatever I choose as seed...  does anyone have a clue?

Code for a 5x5 table:

```
\chgrand[first=0, last=4, counter=kids]
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
\forloop{row_number}{1}{\value{row_number} < 6}{%%
    \forloop{col_number}{1}{\value{col_number} < 5}{%%%
       \rand\arabic{kids} & 
    }%%%
    \rand\arabic{kids}
    \\ }%%
\end{tabular}
```

creates:

```
4 4 4 4 4
4 4 4 4 4
4 4 4 4 4
4 4 4 4 4
4 4 4 4 4
```

doesn't look random to me...

I tried changing `\rand` to `\rand\rand` and all entries changed to '3'. So I presume every time I call `\rand` it starts back from the same seed, but I don't see why, as the seed is declared before the `\forloop`.  Or isn't it?

Comment: This seems appropriate, while looking for an answer http://dilbert.com/dyn/str_strip/000000000/00000000/0000000/000000/00000/2000/300/2318/2318.strip.gif

Comment: Probably your `\forloop` puts a group around the body. Package `lcg` uses local assignments, thus the internal state is reset after the group.

Comment: i could add something like `\chgrand[seed=\value{rand}]` inside the `\forloop`, but that hardly seems a workaround to me (i guess that would lead to the same re-occuring sequence over and over again)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: so i'd have to change to `\foreach`?  or to another random number generator?

Comment: `\foreach` of `pgf` also puts a group around the loop body.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek `\forloop` doesn't use grouping. But being in a `\halign` it was TeX itself that provided the groups.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you're doing that inside a table cell and TeX doesn't like it very much. It's better to build up the token list before doing the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lcg,forloop}
\newtoks\dierckxtoks
\newcounter{row_number}\newcounter{col_number}

\begin{document}

\chgrand[first=0, last=4, counter=kids]
\dierckxtoks={}

\forloop{row_number}{1}{\value{row_number} < 6}{% 
  \forloop{col_number}{1}{\value{col_number} < 5}{%  
     \rand
     \edef\x{\the\dierckxtoks\arabic{kids} &}
     \dierckxtoks\expandafter{\x}%
  }%  
  \rand
  \edef\x{\the\dierckxtoks\arabic{kids} \noexpand\\}
  \dierckxtoks\expandafter{\x}%
}  

\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
\the\dierckxtoks
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, as shown in my first comment, also 444444444 *can* be a sequence of random numbers. `:-)`

---

#### The mandatory `expl3` solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lcg}
\newcounter{randnumb}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\randomtabular}{ O{randnumb} m m m m }
% #1 = counter name (optional default randnumb)
% #2 = lowest value
% #3 = highest value
% #4 = rows
% #5 = columns
 {
  \chgrand[first=#2, last=#3, counter=#1]
  \dierckx_random_tabular:nnn {#1}{#4}{#5}
 }
\tl_new:N \l_dierckx_tabular_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \dierckx_random_tabular:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_dierckx_tabular_tl
  \prg_replicate:nn { #2 }
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn { #3 - 1 }
     {
      \rand
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l_dierckx_tabular_tl { \arabic{#1} & }
     }
    \rand
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_dierckx_tabular_tl { \arabic{#1} }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_dierckx_tabular_tl { \\ }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{*{#3}{r}}
  \l_dierckx_tabular_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\randomtabular{0}{9}{6}{4}

\randomtabular[kids]{0}{4}{5}{5}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A different solution using the random number facility of `pgf`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\randomtabular}{ m m m m }
% #1 = lowest value
% #2 = highest value
% #3 = rows
% #4 = columns
 {
  \dierckx_random_tabular:nnnn {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
 }
\tl_new:N \l__dierckx_tabular_tl
\int_new:N \l__dierckx_random_number_int
\cs_new_protected:Npn \dierckx_random_tabular:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_dierckx_tabular_tl
  \prg_replicate:nn { #3 }
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn { #4 - 1 }
     {
      \dierckx_get_rand:nn { #1 } { #2 }
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l_dierckx_tabular_tl { \int_to_arabic:n { \l__dierckx_random_number_int } & }
     }
    \dierckx_get_rand:nn { #1 } { #2 }
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_dierckx_tabular_tl { \int_to_arabic:n { \l__dierckx_random_number_int } }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_dierckx_tabular_tl { \\ }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{*{#3}{r}}
  \l_dierckx_tabular_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \dierckx_get_rand:nn #1 #2
 {
  \pgfmathrandominteger{ \l__dierckx_random_number_int } { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\randomtabular{0}{9}{6}{4}

\bigskip

\randomtabular{0}{4}{5}{5}

\end{document}
```

There is no optional argument any more, but it doesn't seem to be really necessary.

---

A variant of the first `expl3` solution that pads the number with zeros to have the same length as the highest possible chosen number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lcg}
\newcounter{randnumb}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\randomtabular}{ O{randnumb} m m m m }
% #1 = counter name (optional default randnumb)
% #2 = lowest value
% #3 = highest value
% #4 = rows
% #5 = columns
 {
  \int_set:Nn \l_dierckx_padto_int { \tl_count:n { #3 } }
  \chgrand[first=#2, last=#3, counter=#1]
  \dierckx_random_tabular:nnn {#1}{#4}{#5}
 }
\tl_new:N \l_dierckx_tabular_tl
\tl_new:N \l_dierckx_temp_tl
\int_new:N \l_dierckx_padto_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__dierckx_padnumber:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_dierckx_temp_tl { \arabic{#1} }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_dierckx_temp_tl
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn { \l_dierckx_padto_int - \tl_count:N \l_dierckx_temp_tl } { 0 }
    \l_dierckx_temp_tl
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l_dierckx_tabular_tl { \l_dierckx_temp_tl #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \dierckx_random_tabular:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_dierckx_tabular_tl
  \prg_replicate:nn { #2 }
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn { #3 - 1 }
     {
      \rand
      \__dierckx_padnumber:nn { #1 } { & }
     }
    \rand
    \__dierckx_padnumber:nn { #1 } { }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_dierckx_tabular_tl { \\ }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{*{#3}{r}}
  \l_dierckx_tabular_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\randomtabular{0}{100000}{6}{4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do accept `4444...4` to be a possible random sequence...  but...  with a `2^31` space for `seed` the odds to get this sequence with a random seed are about `0.3E-8`.  And i tried different seeds...  besides, as `\rand\rand` changed the complete table, one can be pretty sure something was wrong.  But I'm glad someone pointed me on what exactly was wrong...

Comment: i dropped the second part of code in a `.sty` file.  so i'm able to reuse them from now on.

Comment: If you choose the max number as, say 100 000, how can you get the random numbers to print zeros for numbers like 00257 and 03498?

Comment: @azetina There should be a question about padding a number with zeros.

Comment: @egreg Let me search and see what I can find about padding with zeros. I was about to ask about how to create a random number table for a statistics class I am teaching and I stumbled upon your answer. Am amazed as to how you achieved it. I am still a little puzzled as to some parts of the expl3 coding but I will look into it before I make further comments. Thanks :)

Comment: @azetina I added a variant for you.

Comment: @egreg How nice of you. Thanks. I will look into the way you wrote your code and try to grasp the expl3 commands. Its not that its complex but its hard for to keep up with all the expl3 language. :) You are the expl3 guru jaja

Answer (score 10):

I made a quick `tikz` solution. You may use `\pgfmathsetseed{}` for repeatable results.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,5}{
        \foreach \y in {1,...,5}{
        \pgfmathrandominteger{\a}{0}{4}
            \node at (\x/2,\y/2){\a};
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

result:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short example. The `\tal` command generates a random number. The `\sekscifret` command uses `\tal` and generates and writes a number with 6 digits. The loop inside the table inserts such numbers in columns and rows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lcg}
\usepackage{forloop}

\newcounter{ct}
\newcounter{ctA}
\newcommand{\tal}{\chgrand[first=0,last=9,counter=randTal]\rand\arabic{randTal}}
\newcommand{\sekscifret}{\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 7}{\tal}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r r r r}

\forloop{ctA}{1}{\value{ctA} < 7}{

\sekscifret&\sekscifret&\sekscifret&\sekscifret
\\}

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```