# TeX as a programming language: examples and design patterns

Tags: tex-core, programming, examples

I'm looking for simple examples of using TeX as a programming language, not LaTeX, and ideally these examples only use the primitive TeX commands. Why? Because the members of a local computer club take turns talking about offbeat languages, and it will be my turn soon. The audience ranges from programming neophytes to people with a sophisticated understanding of computer science. I'm trying to come up with examples that everyone can understand, and that also demonstrate how TeX "works."

I'm aware of a few examples along these lines, not all of which are as primitive as I would like:

[Count the number of elements of each size in a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233193/count-the-number-of-elements-of-each-size-in-a-list)

[Position of largest element in a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231558/position-of-largest-element-in-a-list)

[Count number of elements in a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246923/count-number-of-elements-in-a-list)

[Find the number of elements in a list that occurs most often](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234489/find-the-number-of-elements-in-a-list-that-occurs-most-often)

[Macros with binary trees as arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142002/macros-with-binary-trees-as-arguments)

[How to produce a list of prime numbers in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134305/how-to-produce-a-list-of-prime-numbers-in-latex)

[How to make the last word in a sequence the first](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89304/how-to-make-the-last-word-in-a-sequence-the-first)

[\rand inside \forloop creates identical values](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78988/rand-inside-forloop-creates-identical-values)

[Stack datastructure using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45946/stack-datastructure-using-latex)

[Delete and element from a comma delimited list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5754/delete-an-element-from-a-comma-delimited-list)

As long as we're making a list, it's worth including things on the fun/crazy end of the spectrum too. I'm aware of:

[a brainf**k intepreter](https://github.com/blefloch/latex-runner/blob/master/runner-brainfuck.dtx)

[BaSiX -- An Interpreter Written in TeX](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb11-3/tb29greene.pdf)

[Lists in TeX's Mouth (lambda calculus in TeX)](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/generic/lambda-lists/lambda-lists.pdf)

[An AVR Emulator written in pure LaTeX](https://gitlab.brokenpipe.de/stettberger/avremu/tree/master)

Finally, are there certain design patterns or paradigms that are particular to TeX (or macro-based languages in general)? Other languages have things like lambdas, or they may be strongly, weakly, dynamically or statically typed. Some languages lean on encapsulation or being object-oriented, and there's a whole universe of design patterns that fall under the umbrella of "object-oriented." TeX seems to be off in its own world.

Comment: The ability of TeX to modify its own syntax should be mentioned, with the famous example https://ctan.org/pkg/xii and also https://ctan.org/pkg/inscrutable.

Comment: I think the two aspects I'd emphasise are macros (i.e. that `\foo` is replaced by it's definition at point-of-use), and expansion (i.e. that some things work by expansion, others by execution, and we sometimes need to keep everything in the input stack to work expandably).

Comment: I wonder if the question is really answerable: it feels very opinion-based

Comment: It's my answer, but I think https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69771 (trimming spaces by expansion) nicely shows off how TeX works in expansion, in a task that people do need in a variety of languages

Comment: Maybe some answers in this link if you haven't already seen them.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104248/70641

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233085/basics-of-parsing?r=SearchResults&s=1|39.6270 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605258/macro-delimited-lists?r=SearchResults&s=2|18.2217

Comment: [Michael Downes' around-the-bend exercises](https://ctan.org/pkg/around-the-bend) might be of interest to you.

Comment: These are all helpful, with the proviso that I'm not trying to make anyone's brain burst (i.e., nothing inscrutable). The around-the-bend exercises are particularly good. Anyway, there's stuff here I can work with. Thanks.

Comment: TeX's macro processor allows to do many things with (partially) fully (text/token) expansion, as Alan Jeffrey describes in his "List in TeX's mouth" article.  In combination with assignments (to define macros, save value into different kind of registers, or do calculations) one can in principle "everything".   To understand TeX's macro expansion capabilities and Alan's article I started to implement various fully expandable sorting routings: my very simple "quicksort" implementation is described in the old article "Sorting in TeX's Mouth" (reprinted in https://www.ntg.nl/maps/14/43.pdf ).